# infinitive vs verb vs gerund

Tags: verbs, gerunds, infinitives

> The presence of a suspending medium does more than simply reduce the
>   interaction energy or force by a factor 3 or 32, as might appear from
>   Eq. (5.26)

I understand what this sentence means but I don't know why 'reduce' is used rather than 'reduces' or 'reducing'.

can you explain the reason and give me other examples like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence can be simplified to produce the form:

"The presence does reduce..."

which changes the meaning somewhat, but not the structure. This should make it clear why "reduces" doesn't work: you can't say "The presence does reduces".

You could alternatively say:

"The presence of a suspending medium achieves more than simply reducing..."

or

"The presence of a suspending medium achieves more than simply reduction of..."

I think the fact that "achieves... reducing" sounds a little better than "does... reducing" indicates that the mind treats "does reduce" as a compound verb despite the presence of intervening words, whereas it treats "achieves" as a standalone verb, which takes a gerund or noun as a direct object.

By contrast, in "He does more than he tells people", "does" does not act as an auxiliary, but as a standalone verb. Thus, the subject needs to be repeated before the second verb, and the verb is in the third person singular.

Comment: The simple answer is: when the auxiliary verb in the emphatic form is used, the auxiliary has to agree in number. You were almost there so I will upvote. :)

Comment: @Lambie Number agreement doesn't come into it. In _…a suspending medium does more than simply reduce the interaction …_, “reduce" is required to be in the plain (infinitival) form, “more” being the head and "than reduce the interaction …" its complement.

Comment: @BillJ I meant to say person as in third person. It is the emphatic use of the  auxiliary in the third person: He does speak English, She did do the homework. It does open if you push hard. I meant to write ***person***.

Comment: Otherwise it would be written with an S: The presence of a suspending medium more than simply reduces.....She did more than explain it. Same thing.

Comment: "Supply" is an infinitive. There is no agreement of any kind, number or person. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> *The presence of a suspending medium does [more than simply reduce the
>   interaction energy or force by a factor 3 or 32, as might appear from
>   Eq. (5.26)].*

The syntax requires *reduce* to be in the plain (infinitival) form. *More* is the head and *than simply reduce the
interaction energy or force ...* its complement.